# Middle partition in quicksort algorithm Python

Tags: python, algorithm

I'm trying to implement quicksort algorithm which uses middle partitioning method. below is my code:

```
def middlepartition(A, p, r):
    pvi = (p + r) // 2
    pv = A[pvi]

    while p < r:
        while p < len(A) and A[p] <= pv:
            p += 1
        while A[r] > pv:
            r -= 1
        if p < r:
            A[p], A[r] = A[r], A[p]
    A[r], A[pvi] = A[pvi], A[r]

    return r


def quicksort(A, p, r):
    if p < r:
        q = middlepartition(A, p, r)
        quicksort(A, p, q - 1)
        quicksort(A, q + 1, r)


A = [0, 1, 5, 23, 0, 2, 5, 56, 79, 3, 65]
quicksort(A, 0, len(A)-1)
print(A)
```

but somehow the code doesn't work fine and I'm really confused. the following is the output:

```
[0, 1, 2, 5, 23, 0, 3, 5, 56, 65, 79]
```

I seriously cant find the mistake...

Comment: I believe the statement ```pvi = (p+r)//2``` is meant to find the midpoint of the array given p = the start and r = the end.  If that is the case it doesn't work for all cases.  It should be something like ```pvi = p + (r -p)//2```.  Also, your functions don't work for cases where length of A is 0 or 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is your mistake:

```
A[r], A[pvi] = A[pvi], A[r]
```

(or at least *a* mistake - there could be other issues).

This bit of code occurs in variants of QuickSort that initially move (swap) the pivot element to the end of the array and then exclude that slot from the body of the partitioning loop. Once the partitioning loop is done, the initial pivot element is moved into place at the point where the pivot index has emerged.

That's not what you're doing here, though - when control reaches the above statement the `pvi` index points to a random element, so the swap messes you up. Just get rid of it - the partitioning loop will have already put the pivot element in the right place at that point.